# why numpy array (skimage object) inside a list wasn't updated when iterated inside a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I'm trying to do some operations on skimage objects.  they are fundamentally numpy arrays.
But it has this weird behavior. If I put them in a list and iterate through the list, the operation doesn't reflect on the array/image.

here is an example. I'm trying to convert it to float type, by using the img_as_float() function

```
import skimage as sk
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte, img_as_float

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


a = np.random.randn(100,100,3).astype(np.uint8)
b = np.random.randn(100,100,3).astype(np.uint8)

a = img_as_float(a)
l = [a , b]

for ar in l:
    ar = img_as_float(ar)
    print(ar.dtype)

for ar in l:
    print(ar.dtype)
```

I get

```
float64
float64
float64
uint8
```

the function itself works, but inside the for loop it doesn't work, or at least didn't update the object b as I wantted.

to be clear, eventually, I want a loop/function to change a and b.

Any clues and suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you do `for ar in l:`, `ar` is a reference on the item of the list. Doing `ar = ...` causes `ar` to be a reference of something else. It does *not* set the referenced item. Since the left-hand side and the right-hand side of the expression are of a different type, you cannot do a copy (using something like `ar[:,:] = ...`). **You need to use a range-based loop**:

```py
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = img_as_float(l[i])
    print(l[i].dtype)

for i in range(len(l)):
    print(l[i].dtype)
```

Comment: hi! Thanks for the answer!  Indeed I tried your method it and it gives float in the for loop. However, if later I check 'print(b.dtype)',  I'll find that b is still unit8.  My final purpose is to change a and b (as I have a long list of images to treat).  Can you think of anything I can do?  Thanks!

Comment: This is normal, `a` and `b` are referencing the initial arrays and changing the reference in the loop does not have to impact `a` and `b`. If you want to change the two variables, then you need to set them explicitly. For example: `a, b = l`.

Comment: There is a very good tutorial on this from Ned Batchelder here: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html